# Recursive template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++20

Is the following code ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/d8cevTM1M)) conformant to the C++20 specifications? And why or why not? Clang and GCC seem to be in disagreement as Clang 14.0.0 happily compiles the given example.

```
struct s {
    template<typename T>
    inline static auto f
        = [](){ return T::template g<s>; };
};

struct t {
    template<typename T>
    inline static auto g
        = [](){ return T::template f<t>; };
};

auto main() -> int {
    s::f<t>();
}
```

The error produced by GCC 12.1:

```
<source>:4:36:   required from 'auto s::f<t>'
<source>:14:8:   required from here
<source>:10:36: error: use of 's::f<t>' before deduction of 'auto'
   10 |         = [](){ return T::template f<t>; };
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
<source>:10:36: error: use of 's::f<t>' before deduction of 'auto'
```

Interestingly, when invoking the instantion of `s::f`, as in `s::f<t>()();`, Clang seems to give out completely.

Comment: Looks UB to me. Your program doesn't make any forward progress.

Comment: What do you expect the return types to be?

Comment: I have no expectations of the return types, I'm fine with whatever the Clang compiler makes of it.

Comment: Then what's the point? Why are you returning something? Just make it `[](){}` and be done with it. [Note: I'm trying to make you think about the solution here ;)]

Comment: The solution I'm looking for is that both compilers, GCC and Clang, produce the same result. They should either both compile the code without errors or both produce errors, whatever the standard mandates.

Comment: @303 if it falls into undefined or implementation-defined territory - good luck with that

Comment: Well, finding out if it does would be a start.

Comment: The standard does not mandate everything. Many things are left undefined by omission.

Comment: ... though this is not one of those cases. This is a very obvious clang bug [minimal reproduction](https://godbolt.org/z/4PYjaM6ev). Making `f` a non-template causes clang emit the same type of diagnostic gcc does [reproduction](https://godbolt.org/z/WWsczjhEW).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think the standard gives **any** satisfactory answer here because it doesn’t describe the process of template instantiation in any detail.  The practical problem is of course that each closure type is the return type of the other, so that it depends on how the implementation creates the closure types: if it decides that the type of the static member variable template specialization is the closure type and then processes its `operator()`, it works, and if it does these in the other order it doesn’t.  Note that the lambdas **copy** one another, so the compiler has to have analyzed the (defaulted) copy constructor too.

Comment: Well, I do find this situation a bit peculiar. From my point of view, the code is quite a small and trivial example. Admittedly, it's somewhat counterintuitive and less obvious in nature, but still, it's not going to extreme lengths to ponder in some of the darker corners of undefined behavior land. So, I would expect the standard to at least formulate some sort of restrictive rule about template instantations that are of a similar nature. I usually feel especially compelled to consult the standard when the two main stream compilers are in disagreement about a piece of code. ...

Comment: ... Being informed (by others) to not have these kinds of expectations leaves an impression that is rather surprising to me and I'm not sure in what regard my view of things should be changed.

Comment: @303: When templates were designed, the thought was “It’s just a class, but with these parameters supplied!”.  The standard still speaks in those terms: consider that template instantiations are supposedly performed in phase 8 after ordinary compilation ([lex.phases]/1.8).  This is of course nonsense: just parsing `X<1>::y*z` requires checking partial specializations of `X` and performing an arbitrary amount of SFINAE and other instantiations to find out whether `y` is a type.  [Someday](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2) someone will volunteer to rewrite all that.